# Does this sound like a wiring problem or a fixture problem?

Tags: wiring

I've lived in my house for two years.  Very recently, I switched on the light in my bathroom and noticed the light switch buzzing.  The lights blinked and seemed to struggle to come on.  I turned it off and left it, trying it again later to see if it was a fluke.  It was not.  Yesterday, I was going to show this problem to my uncle to get his opinion...when I flipped the switch, nothing happened.  No buzzing, no lights, nothing.  This particular switch controls a medicine cabinet/vanity above my sink.  I'm sure it's quite old but I have no idea how old it is.  I'm pretty confident this is not a breaker issue, as the other bathroom switch and my closet both work.

I am confident I will have to have an electrician come in and work on it, but I'd like to know if this is a wiring issue or a fixture issue or both before I call.   I know it won't be 100% until someone comes to look at it, but having an idea would help curb my anxiety a little bit.

Comment: Probably a loose or dirty connection.  With the breaker off I would change to a new switch(for the fun of it since they are cheap) and check all connections for tightness.  Take pictures before removing any wires.

Answer (score 3):

To me, it sounds like the switch has failed.  I've seen this happen even with brand new Levitons.  The problem can be confirmed with a continuity tester, but the switch must be removed from the circuit before testing it.

If the switch can be confirmed normal without any obvious connection problem or breaker trip then you would have to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 2):

"noticed the light switch buzzing"
This is a solid indication that the problem is in the switch or at least in the switch box. A loose connection is more likely than a bad switch - but it could be either.

- Turn off the power to the switch box. This may require shutting down the main.
- Once you remove the faceplate, remove the screws holding the switch to the box.
- Carefully pull the switch out from the box leaving all wires connected.
- Check the wires attached to the switch screws and make sure the wires are firmly secured by the screws. **The wires should not be attached through the backstabs on the back of the switch.** If they are they should be removed from the backstabs, stripped and reconnected with the screws.
- Check all of the wire nut connections in the box making sure they are securely tightened.

Carefully reassemble the switch and faceplate and test. If this doesn't solve the problem, the switch is probably defective and you should replace it.